# gvim syntax highlight for "-"

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

How to make gvim syntax highlight to recognise `"-"` in front of keyword. In my code I have many words like -o, -l, -d.
I need gvim syntax highlight to recognize them.

When I try:

```
syn keyword outputStatement    -o
syn keyword logStatement       -l

hi def link outputStatement   PreProc
hi def link logStatement      Statement
```

gvim does not recognize. But if I remove "-" then everything works fine.

I tried many combinations such as "-o", '-o', {-o},... nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a pre-installed `syntax/sdc.vim` file? Mine has the following commands

```
syn match sdcFlags "[[:space:]]-[[:alpha:]]*\>"
hi def link sdcFlags Special
```

which can highlight the `-setup` switch in the example code below

```
set_clock_uncertainty -setup 2 [all_clocks]
```

Hope this can help you.